# Market requires the minSdkVersion to be set to a positive 32-bit integer in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: google-play, android-manifest

We get this message every time time we try to upload our apk.
"Market requires the minSdkVersion to be set to a positive 32-bit integer in AndroidManifest.xml."
We have search and found many answer but none seem to fit our code. Any help would very accepted. Thank You.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.app.MobileClient"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".MobileClient" 
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

immediatly under the  tag add a  tag such as:

```
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="9" />
```